# Are there color pickers for Emacs?

Tags: colors

I use the excellent `rainbow-mode` to highlight colors in CSS files.

[image: css with rainbow-mode]

However, this assumes I know what color I want. Are there any color pickers that I can use for CSS editing inside Emacs? Ideally, I'd really like something where I can make colors slightly darker/brighter/redder/greener, like the Firefox color picker:

[image: firefox color picker]

Alternatively, I've noticed `customize-face` offers a color picker from a set of 548 colors. Can I use this for CSS?

[image: customize-face color picker]

Comment: I can't resist quoting an exchange that dates back to the early days of Emacs: "Master, does Emacs have buddha-nature?" "... I can't see why not; it has everything else."

Comment: Thanks for bringing up `rainbow-mode`! I was looking for just this feature and couldn't remember which package it was in.

Answer (score 20):

Have a look at `helm-colors`.  It presents the colors exactly as in your screenshot and seems to be using a similar or even the same palette.

To insert a color name into the current buffer, press <kbd>C-c n</kbd> (runs the action `Insert Name`).

To insert the hex value of a color, press <kbd>C-c r</kbd> (run the action `Insert RGB`).

Comment: I second `helm-colors`. Here is a [demo](http://tuhdo.github.io/static/part3/helm-color.gif) for anyone interests in how it looks like. You can select a color and insert it right into your editing buffers.

Comment: `helm-colors` is excellent, but it doesn't seem to replace the at point, nor even insert in the buffer. Ideally I'd like something that supported arbitrary colors.

Comment: @WilfredHughes It does have. You need to look at the action menu, by pressing `TAB` (the default key binding, use yours if you bind to something else). See my [helm-colors section](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-24) in my guide.

Comment: If you want to insert a color with its hex value, press `C-c r`.

Answer (score 16):

- Library [**Palette**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorPalette) ([`palette.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/palette.el)) gives you a general WYSIWYG color editor/picker, which lets you explore and modify colors using RGB and HSV values, including incrementally. It looks like what you show in your second image.
- Library [**Do Re Mi**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DoReMi) ([`doremi.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/doremi.el),  [`doremi-cmd.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/doremi-cmd.el), [`doremi-frm.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/doremi-frm.el)) lets you modify colors used in Emacs incrementally: "direct manipulation".
- Library **Facemenu+** ([`facemenu+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/facemenu+.el)) lets you use the color palette (#1) to change colors used in Emacs. It enhances standard library `facemenu.el`, things like `list-colors-display` and `list-faces-display` (which look similar to your 3rd image).
- Library [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) lets you choose and manipulate colors and faces incrementally, manipulating RGB, HSV, etc. and sorting possible choices in many ways (e.g. combining color-component strengths).

(You can get the libraries mentioned here from [MELPA](http://www.melpa.org), and the Lisp files contain the full documentation (but without images).)

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```el
(defun my-insert-color-hex (&optional arg)
  "Select a color and insert its 24-bit hexadecimal RGB format.

With prefix argument \\[universal-argument] insert the 48-bit value."
  (interactive "*P")
  (let ((buf (current-buffer)))
    (list-colors-display
     nil nil `(lambda (name)
                (interactive)
                (quit-window)
                (with-current-buffer ,buf
                  (insert (apply #'color-rgb-to-hex
                                 (nconc (color-name-to-rgb name)
                                        (unless (consp ',arg)
                                          (list (or ,arg 2)))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [emacsfodder/kurecolor](https://github.com/emacsfodder/kurecolor).

- convert colors between different formats

  - `#RRGGBB`(`AA`) `hex` colors to/from CSS `rgb()`/`rgba()`
  - XCode `colorLiteral` to/from `hex` colors
  - `rgb` to/from `hsv`
- interactive incremental step adjust hue,sat,brightness on a single color at point
- adjust or set hue,sat,brightness on all colors found in a region/buffer (from point)