# Is there a color selector in Emacs, that reads the HTML color under cursor?

Tags: package, colors, coloring

As an alternative to [the awesome vCoolor plugin](https://github.com/KabbAmine/vCoolor.vim).

I tried to find alternatives in Emacs. When you do `M-x color`. You see a list of possible color functions. But nothing of them reads the color under the cursor and lets you input the HTML color (e.g. `#BD9800`). 
Or something in that way.

Is there any function or package that offers same functionality as the vCoolor plugin for Vim?

Comment: Closely related: [Are there color pickers for Emacs?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/are-there-color-pickers-for-emacs)

Comment: Not clear. What do you mean by "read the color under the cursor"? Pick up the foreground or background color there? Read a color name there? Read an RGB hex code there? And what do you mean by "lets you input the HTML color"? Input how, for what? Input by typing such an RBG hex code? To do what? You mention of vCoolor suggests that you are looking for a color picker, in which case this looks like a [duplicate](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5582/105).

Comment: @Drew, I mean the RGB color, where currently under the pointer is.